# How to authenticate the user in offline mode in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

Am developing a Windows Store 8.1 app using C# and xaml.

In the app, Initially user will log in into the app using Azure Active directory single sign on log in(With Internet connection)

But how to authenticate the user  in Azure Active Directory when the user is not connected to the internet?

I want my app to work in  offline mode too..

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

When you 'log in', there should be an artifact produced. In the case of OpenIdConnect there is an id_token, OAuth produces an AccessToken. If those are captured and stored securely, then there will be evidence that the user did authenticate to AAD at one time. The artifacts of that 'log in' have expiration times.

Backing up, when a user logs in, how is that identity used? Do you managed protected resources yourself OR do you reach out for them?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **SQL lite** and save the user's details in it by encrypting it..
The next time when he logs into the app you can simple validate his credentials against his details from the DB like you would do in any website/webapp.

**Side note** : We have a service which runs in the background every 4 hours to check if the user's credentials have changed, if its changed fetches the new credentials and updates it in the local sql lite db

Comment: Hi Karthik,
 Am using Azure AD login, so im unable to get the password from AD service.
 I do get authentication token, how to get the password from the authentication token?

Comment: How do you tie a user to an auth token? When a user logs in with the oauth web page, you get an auth token back, but how do you know who the user is to put them in your database? I'd like to send  a payload along with the oauth request that I can get back, but that doesn't seem to exist...